# jquery appendTo effect fade when load from function div

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I try to add HTML content all time with this little script, buy i can't get the animation to show when opening and create this div in the fly

```
function add(id)
{
var holdyDiv=jQuery("<div>Hello"+id+"</div>");

holdyDiv.appendTo('body').fadeIn(3000);
}


<a onclick="add('test');">OPEN</a>
```

I suppose however `fadeIn` must show this effect when opening or append div, but don't get results

My question is, it's about what is bad and why don't this div load with `fadeIn` effect, thanks.

Comment: add your html code

Comment: The HTML code it´s you can see in var jQuery("<div>Hello</div>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fadeIn first before appending it to body.

```js
var holdyDiv=jQuery("<div>Hello</div>");

holdyDiv.fadeIn(3000).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or hide it first

```js
 var holdyDiv=jQuery("<div>Hello</div>");

    holdyDiv.hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn(3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **hide** content first: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/eKMyYW

```
function add(id) {
    var holdyDiv = jQuery("<div>Hello" + id + "</div>");
    holdyDiv.hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn(3000);
}
```

Comment: The Problem it´s i launch this function from link and inside have some strings, i change my examle

Comment: I have update code and codepen. it will work for your code update code also!!

Comment: I don´t know why but i change my example and i call from link and if use hide, never show me nothing, y i delete hide show but don´t show effec

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(id) {
    var holdyDiv = jQuery("<div>Hello" + id + "</div>");
    holdyDiv.fadeIn(3000).appendTo('body');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a onclick="add('test');">OPEN</a>
</body>
```

You need to replace `holdyDiv.appendTo('body').fadeIn(3000);`
 to  `holdyDiv.fadeIn(3000).appendTo('#printData');` will solve your problem :-)

Comment: I need append to body, it´s not possible add to body ?

Answer (score 0):

It's more specific, initially we hide div at first load, then we show/hide (toggle) it when click on link.

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
  var elem = jQuery('<div id="test"></div>');
  jQuery("body").append(elem);
  elem.hide();
});


function add(text) {
  holdyDiv = jQuery('#test').html('Hello '+text+' !!');
  jQuery('#test').fadeToggle('fast');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="add('Test');">Show/hide div</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers